# MASS::stepAIC - assignment to steps function argument

Tags: r

Can someone explain why the following code in R gives different results depending on whether `=` or `<-` is used to assign the `steps` argument:

```
library(MASS)
quine.hi <- aov(log(Days + 2.5) ~ .^4, quine)
quine.nxt <- update(quine.hi, . ~ . - Eth:Sex:Age:Lrn)

quine.stp <- stepAIC(quine.nxt,
                     scope = list(upper = ~Eth*Sex*Age*Lrn, lower = ~1),
                     trace = TRUE,
                     steps = 6)

quine.stp_2 <- stepAIC(quine.nxt,
                       scope = list(upper = ~Eth*Sex*Age*Lrn, lower = ~1),
                       trace = TRUE,
                       steps <- 6)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<-` and `=` are not interchangeable in function calls. It should be surprising when the results are the same, not different. `=` is used to name parameters in function class; `->` does not provide names.

This means that when you call

```
stepAIC(quine.nxt,
  scope = list(upper = ~Eth*Sex*Age*Lrn, lower = ~1),
  trace = TRUE,
  steps <- 6)
```

that 4th parameter is not named. It's evaluated and just returns 6 (the `->` operator returns the RHS value as a return value) and is treated as an unnamed parameter. Unnamed parameters are passed in the order in which they are received to a function after plugging in the all the named values. The `stepAIC` function signature is

```
stepAIC(object, scope, scale ,
    direction, trace, keep , steps , use.start ,k = 2, ...)
```

So since you've specified `scope=` and `trace=`, the value of `6` will go into the `scale=` parameter. So what you've written is the same as

```
stepAIC(quine.nxt,
  scope = list(upper = ~Eth*Sex*Age*Lrn, lower = ~1),
  trace = TRUE,
  6)
```

which is the same as

```
stepAIC(quine.nxt, 
  scope = list(upper = ~Eth*Sex*Age*Lrn, lower = ~1),
  scale = 6,
  trace = TRUE)
```

So the important message is that `<-` should only be used for assignment, and `=` should only be used to name parameters in function calls.